# Export the config of particular servers in Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Now my Zabbix is monitoring both prod and dev environments.

I want to setup a new Zabbix server, which is intended to monitor dev environment and keep the old one to monitor prod environment.

Is there any efficient way to "export" the dev server config and import in new Zabbix?
so that I don't need to configure the dev server one by one.

Comment: Copy the database. Also you should probably not have two zabbix servers in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can export hosts. Just go to Configuration->Hosts, check all hosts you want and click on export (bottom of the page)